# Check if a node is fully selected

Tags: javascript, range, rangy

I'm using rangy in my project. I want to test if an element is fully selected. I tried the following:

```html
selRange.containsNode( el );
```

Note: selRange is simply a reference to window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);

When the selection was made from top to the bottom, it works but not the other way around.

Safari and Chrome return different results depending if you made a bottom up or top down selection. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exactly what is considered selected depends on how the selection was made and which browser you're using. If you're just interested in whether all of the text within an element is selected, Rangy's `Range` object provides a [non-standard convenience method](https://github.com/timdown/rangy/wiki/Rangy-Range#containsnodetextnode-node) for this:

```
selRange.containsNodeText(el);
```

Here is a non-Rangy equivalent. It isn't fully tested but I think it will work.

```
function containsNodeText(range, node) {
    var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(node,
        NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,
        { acceptNode: function(node) { return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT; } },
        false
    );
    var firstTextNode, lastTextNode, textNode;
    while ( (textNode = treeWalker.nextNode()) ) {
        if (!firstTextNode) {
            firstTextNode = textNode;
        }
        lastTextNode = textNode;
    }
    var nodeRange = range.cloneRange();
    if (firstTextNode) {
        nodeRange.setStart(firstTextNode, 0);
        nodeRange.setEnd(lastTextNode, lastTextNode.length);
    } else {
        nodeRange.selectNodeContents(node);
    }
    return range.compareBoundaryPoints(Range.START_TO_START, nodeRange) < 1 &&
        range.compareBoundaryPoints(Range.END_TO_END, nodeRange) > -1;
}
```

Comment: You can read minds. That's exactly what I needed. containsNode doesn't behave consistently across browsers. Safari only reports that it contains the node if the selection actually goes beyond the element itself. Thank you!!

Comment: what would be the easiest approach to handle this without rangy?

Comment: @AdrianZumbrunnen: I've knocked up an equivalent.

Comment: Interesting approach. I've come up with the following:

`
Selection.prototype.isFullySelected = function( range, element ){
        var result = this.getNodes().some( function( node ){
            var el = node.nodeType === 1 ? node : node.parentNode;
            return el === element && ( trange.toString().indexOf( element.textContent ) >= 0) && this.selection.containsNode( node, false );
        }.bind( this ));
        return result;
    }

`

whereas getNodes is similar to rangy.getNodes, it gets me an array of all the selected nodes within the range.

it's certainly not as accurate though

Comment: Saved me lots of time, exactly what i needed, Thanks a lot